# Django change the way date field is displayed in django admin

Tags: django, datetime, django-models

That's it i want to change the way its displayed cause it says "noon" or "midnight" and i want i to display the exact hour

I've got this code on the field

```
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, default=datetime.date.today())
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options.

1. Override `DATETIME_FORMAT`, read here: [datetime format](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#datetime-format)
2. Use a form for your model and in the date attribute have some like this(
   in input format, put whatrever you want):

   `date = forms.DateTimeField(input_format="%b %d %Y %I:%M%p")`
3. Or just change the way you render your datetime field in the template:

   `{{ your_model.date_field|date:'Y-m-d H:i' }}`